# how to generate Cron expression for special day?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net, cronexpression

it is a interesting question. i am using Quartz.net to make job scheduler. also [CronMaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) is good for understanding crontrigger expressions. But i want to generate special day trigger. For example:
EXAMPLE1:

Run Times per 15 minutes :
03.04.2012 13:45   (starttime)

03.04.2012 14:00   (next run time)

Also
EXAMPLE2:

only one working : 03.04.2012 (13:45 only one )

How to write EXAMPLE1 and EXAMPLE2 cron expressions?

Comment: for example 2, to run once a cronjob, you would need the command **at**

Comment: @Gero : i dont understand sorry

Comment: the word "at" is a linux command. http://www.brunolinux.com/02-The_Terminal/The_at_Command.html -- just google **command at linux**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EXAMPLE1: Run Times per 15 minutes start from 13:45:00 and only run on 03-APR-2012

Create 2 Cron expressions:

- Run Times on 03-APR-2012 13:45:00 and run exactly once

> `0 45 13 3 APR ? 2012`

- Run Times since 03-APR-2012 14:00:00 , repeat per 15 minutes and only run on 03-APR-2012

> `0 /15 14-23 3 APR ? 2012`

---

EXAMPLE2: Run Times on 03-APR-2012 13:45:00 and run exactly once

```
0 45 13 3 APR ? 2012
```

---

EXAMPLE3: RUN Times from 03.04.2012 13:45:00 to 12.04.2012 15:45:00 per 15 minutes

It can be spilt into the following triggers:

- For 03.04.2012  , use two trigger from Example 1
- For 04.04.2012 - 11-04.2012 , use

> ```
>  0 /15 * 4-11 APR ? 2012
> ```

- For 12.04.2012 , use the following triggers

> `0 /15 0-15 12 APR ? 2012`

For simplicity , I will use the `CronTriggerImpl` to build this schedule as it contains the method to set the start time and end time for a cron expression  .

In this way , I can make the  cron expression that always repeats 15 minutes and set the  start time and end time to limit this schedule to be executed in a defined date range.

Comment: i really want to say more thanks. But * 45 13 3 APR ? 2012 is working per second. How to improve this problem? Also i have a little question: From  03.04.2012 13:45 TO 12.04.2012 15:45 PER 15 minutes How to do it?

Comment: your soliton is good. But i guess yo misunderstand me : "Run Times from 03.04.2012 14:00:00 to 03.04.2012 15:45:00 , repeat per 15 minutes" you writed. But My last Time RUN Times from 03.04.2012 13:45:00 to 12.04.2012 15:45:00 per 15 minutes. i guess it must be : 0 0,15,30,45 14-15 3-12 APR ? 2012. are you sure?

Comment: From 03.04.2012 12:30 to 12.07.2013 17:40  PER 5 minutes : 0 /5 12-17 3-7 APR-JUL2012-2013 is it true? or any solution?

Comment: No , at least it will not runs on JAN , FEB, MAR , AUG, SEPT .... and also will not runs on from 17:00pm to 23:59 pm  every day. Actually , I think you can apply the same logic of EXAMPLE3 to split the schedule into several cron expressions in this case. Besides , I think it should be helpful to you :http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.1.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-06

Comment: Ken; Really really thanks:( nut i have a last question : 0 0/1 14-17 3-20 APR ? 2012 is meaning of  from 03.04.2012  to 20.04.2012 is it?

Comment: Yes . It means 14:00 - 17:00 from 03.04.2012 to 20.04.2012 . During this time , the job will be executed once per one minute.